# How to trim 0 in day but not in month with format(yyyy-dd-mm) in angular/javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I trim javascript date object. I have a date which format is (yyyy-d-m).
The date value is `2015-03-03` and I want to trim the first 0 in days but not in months.

Example: When I input:
`2015-03-03` it will returned `2015-3-03`

I tried the following code but it's also trim the `0` in months.

```
 $scope.date = {
     "start": "2015-01-26",
     "end": "2015-04-03"
 };

  `var from = $scope.date.from.replace(/\b0(?=\d)/g, '');
   var to = $scope.date.to.replace(/\b0(?=\d)/g, '');
   console.log(to);
   //output 2015-1-26 and 2015-4-3`
```

What should I do?

Comment: Changing `2015-03-03`  to `2015-3-03` is removing the leading zero from the month, not day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove the leading zero from the day, then:

```
$scope.date.from.replace(/-0(\d)$/,'-$1')
```

will do. There is no need for lookahead or the *g* flag (since you're only replacing one instance).

#### Edit

Sorry, I should have explained how the regular expression and replacement works.

In the regular expression, `-0(\d)$` matches a dash, followed by a zero, followed by a digit, followed by the end of the string. The brackets `( )` capture the matched digit in a hold space that is represented in the replacement string by `$1`.

The whole match is then replaced by the replacement string `'-$1'` which is a dash, followed by the matched digit: `$1`.

Comment: Thank you RobG. . That is work fine. . Can you explain to me what is the meaning and used of `'-$1'`?

Answer (score 0):

add dashes around your regex grouping that you want to exclude, your month does not have dashes on both sides

/\b-0(?=\d)-/g

Comment: Why not `/-0(\d)-/` (if the OP actually wants to remove the month leading zero).