# How to trim 0 in day but not in month (dd-mm-yyyy) in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Actually I need to trim 0 in day not in Month.
 my date Format is `05-03-2016`

I need to get answer like below `5-03-2016`.

Actually there is a answer for this question with different Date format (yyyy-dd-mm). **I am trying to achieve with this format:  (dd-mm-yyyy)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090152/angularjs-javascript-how-to-trim-0-in-day-but-not-in-month let me know is it what you are expecting ?

Comment: `'05-03-2016'.replace(/^0/,'')`

Comment: yeah i know that answer, i have already mentioned it above, but i need that answer in my date format

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateSplit = "05-03-2016".split("-");
dateSplit[0] = dateSplit[0].replace(/^0+/, "");
var finalDate = dateSplit.join("-");
// finalDate = "5-03-2016"
```

Comment: Completely unnecessary to do the split when you can do what _Pranav C Balan_ already showed in a comment

Comment: @Nodemon if it worked for you, mark your question as answered by clicking on the green tick near my answer :)